# Value does not fall within the expected range in Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;

Tags: c#, directx, directsound

I am developing a music player with managed code and I am using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound. I am getting this error "Value does not fall within the expected range" when I calling play method. So, The problem is only for 24 bit WAV files. That was the reason for the exception. For 16 bit files is working fine. Any Ideas how to make it work for 24 bit files too?

Thank you!

```
    using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;
    using DS = Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;
    .......
    private DS.Device sounddevice;
    private DevicesCollection AuioDevList;
    //Create buffer
    private SecondaryBuffer secondaryBuffer;
    private BufferDescription d = new BufferDescription();

    private void initializeSound()
    {
        // List all Audio Cards
        AuioDevList = new DevicesCollection();
        // Populate cmbAudioCards
        cmbAudioCards.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < AuioDevList.Count; i++)
        {
            cmbAudioCards.Items.Add(AuioDevList[i].Description);
        }
        cmbAudioCards.SelectedIndex = 0;
        sounddevice = new DS.Device(AuioDevList[0].DriverGuid);
        sounddevice.SetCooperativeLevel(this.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Normal);

        // Set descriptor’s flags
        d.ControlPan = true;
        d.ControlVolume = true;
        d.ControlFrequency = true;
        d.ControlEffects = true;
    }

    private void prepareSound(string file)
    {

            playing = false;
        //secondaryBuffer.Stop();            
        secondaryBuffer = new SecondaryBuffer(file, d, sounddevice);
        secondaryBuffer.Volume = trkVolume.Value;
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
         //Here is throwing exception 
        secondaryBuffer.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);//
    }
```

Comment: No `play` method. No question.

Comment: @spender Thank you for your comment. But please next time come with an answer

Comment: How is it possible to answer an incomplete question? Your edit makes much more sense, but you still didn't ask anything.

Comment: @spender I am asking.. you don't like my question for some reasons.